# Requesting "call-out" tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-request

I just posted a question that is about adding a ["call out"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/callout) (text with some line pointing at something).
I realized that there is no `call-out` tag yet.
Would it be considered to be too specific?

Example: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/callout.htm

Question that would need it (actually my own question):
[Add a "CallOut" that follows an object with a line in DaVinci Resolve](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/36424/33658)

Comment: You could add this one: [after effects - target edge of null object rather than centre - Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26241/target-edge-of-null-object-rather-than-centre).

Answer (score 1):

We tend to not add tags until they are needed - ie there are a number of questions that would be served well by visitors who want to search on that tag.

Can you edit your post to list which questions you think need it please.